# Using complex logarithms to solve equations

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis

Could someone please just explain the formula/method for solving the complex equation $$e^{iω}=k$$ where $k∈C$.

As an example, I know that when $ω=x+iy$, $e^{2iω}=1$ has solutions $ω = n\pi$ for $n∈Z$ but I'm not sure how to show this properly. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

First try to write $k$ in polar form, i.e., if $k = x+iy$, then $\vert k \vert = \sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ and $\tan(\theta_k) = \dfrac{y}x \implies \theta_k = \arctan\left(\dfrac{y}x\right)$.

Now we want to find $\omega$ such that $e^{i \omega} = \vert k \vert e^{i \theta_k}$. If we let $\omega = \omega_x + i \omega_y$, where $\omega_x, \omega_y \in \mathbb{R}$, we then have
$$e^{-\omega_y} \cdot e^{i \omega_x} = \vert k \vert e^{i \theta_k}$$
Hence, $\omega_y = - \ln(\vert k \vert)$ and $\omega_x = \theta_x + 2 \pi$.